# How do i use user name as diff parameters?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

Need help in solving this I run this script to execute some commands that will run on difference machines will diff username how can I achieve this?

```
cat IP | while read LINE
do
  echo $LINE >> output.txt
  stackname=$LINE
  ssh -o "BatchMode=yes" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -t -t -i test.pem ec2-user@$stackname "bash -s" <  sh.sh
done
```

Comment: Sorry my bad type error I am running this script that will fetch the ip from a file and use key with different user names to login many instances?

Question here is how will add a condition that will user 1st usernanme if not executed use the 2nd ?

Answer (score 0):

Put Usernames in a textfile. With a second "for loop" you can compare every IP with every Username eg:

```
cat IP | while read LINE
 cat Usernames | while read USER
  ssh [...] $USER@$LINE
  if [ $? -eq "0" ]; then
   break
  else
   continue
  fi
 done
done
```

after SSH-Command, the Errorcode (in var $?) is 0, if login correct. the inner "Username" loop will break, otherwise it will continue with next Username.

Comment: Thanks @Tobias I have how do i add the same script

cat IPDIR | while read LINE
do
  echo $LINE >> output.txt
  stackname=$LINE
  ssh -o "BatchMode=yes" -o "StrictHostKeyChecking no" -t -t -i test.pem ec2-user@$stackname "bash -s" <  sh.sh
done

Let me Explain I have all the IP mentioned in the IP DIR  and used variable to use it for SSH using Key with username and then sh.sh is the set of commands that will execute.